kafka.common.KafkaException: number of topics has value -1 which is not in the range (0,2147483647)
one of my client is written in GO and they are using the sarama 1.0.0 library and my kafka is of 1.1.1 version without any security. when client is trying to consume from the topic they are not able to consume and they are getting exception saying no brokers might be available. In reality my cluster is up and running and all other clients are working fine with more than 400 topics. But when I check kafka server logs I can see below exception being thrown for the respective client ip as below.
How to resolve this issue and Could someone explain if this issue is due to incompatibility of client library with current version of kafka or any other issue.
kafka.common.KafkaException: number of topics has value -1 which is not in the range (0,2147483647).
        at kafka.api.ApiUtils$.readIntInRange(ApiUtils.scala:85)
        at kafka.api.TopicMetadataRequest$.readFrom(TopicMetadataRequest.scala:41)
        at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$4.apply(RequestKeys.scala:42)
        at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$4.apply(RequestKeys.scala:42)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:50)
        at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:450)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```



Sarama 1.0.0 was released in 2015. It might be best to upgrade that
